# Can't navigate to setup.exe in FreeDOS

Tags: windows-98

I am installing Windows 98 on computer well based it's expiration date. It lacks an OS. When I pop in the disk (Yes it is bootable), it will display a command prompt at the location A:. However, instead of loading the root of the base, it displays the config.sys file upon typing in "dir". I can not locate the setup file as wherever config.sys is is considered the root (Although for the life of me I can not find it on a working computer).

Comment: `I pop in the disk` - What is this disk you have?  Is this a CD-ROM, or a floppy disk?  Why do you think this disk should have setup on it?  If this is a floppy, are you sure it hasn't been formatted?

Comment: It's a CD, though it is not rewritable. Not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: So you think you are booting off this Windows 98 Install cd?  It should go directly to the installer.  Are you sure you aren't booting off a floppy disk, or the hard drive?

Comment: I believe if he gets the A:\> prompt it is indeed a boot disk, though if only config.sys is on it, it sounds like it came from a format A: /s

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: It is unlikely you are booting the CD due to A:\> prompt. From DOS / bare metal, usually a boot disk would be used to load mscdex and get you CD access.

Comment: autoexec.bat and other files of that nature are also displayed.

Comment: @ssnobobody, it sates that it is using the FreeDos, which is what I put on the disk. There is nothing else inserted into the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the files were in the drive D:. Apparently, someone tried to install an OS on it before and gave up somewhere along the way.